# List item height issue in add sites

Tags: bug, android-app

The list item size is matchparent so each item is occupying the whole screen. Just a simple fix- use wrap content

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: Nexus 5

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (3437181)